# How to choose -Og over -O0 in a Makefile if it is supported

Tags: debugging, gcc, optimization, makefile

GCC >= 4.8 supports the `-Og` command-line option, but prior GCC versions and other compilers are missing this option. How do I choose between `-Og` and `-O0` in a Makefile? If `-Og` is supported the Makefile should use `-Og` and it should fall back to `-O0` otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer:

```
CFLAGS += $(shell $(CC) -Og -E - < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo -Og || echo -O0)
```

Comment: This should work, but looks like the whole thing is going to get executed for every compile, which might slow things down. A more conventional approach is to run this test in the autoconf script. These kinds of configuration issues are precisely autoconf and automake's bread and butter.